# Cordova and Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova

I've got a Cordova app running on my android device. It has the following code:

var socket = io.connect('http://myipwhatever.com');

```
$('#logo').click(function() {
    console.log('logo clicked');
    socket.emit('athing', { somedata: "this data" });
}
```

On my server, I have this code:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {  
    console.log('connection');

    io.sockets.emit('hello');

    socket.on('athing', function(data) {
        console.log('got a thing');
    });
});
```

The client's code connects to the socket, but doesn't emit any events or receive any. The client is getting the button press event. Am I missing something here?

I should note, I'm not seeing any errors on either the client or server side.